# Hosting dynamic Flask website using AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, elastic-beanstalk, flask

I have been trying to host a dynamic Flask website which includes Machine Learning on AWS ElasticBeanstalk. The success message "Environment has succesfully launched" is displayed.

However, in the "environment overview" section the health status is still "No data". When I clicked on the "View causes" link. The following is obtained: "Instance has not sent any data since launch." (The running time is 13 hours).
[Health Status - View causes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvsJ6.png)
[Health Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZDpK.png)

The following steps have been performed:

1. All the required files and folders(.ebextensions folder,static folder, templates folder,
   app.py file, requirements.txt file, pickle file) of the Flask website have been moved to
   a folder and compressed into a zip folder.
2. Navigate to AWS ElasticBeanstalk page and click on "Create application" button.
3. Provide application name.
4. Upload source code.
5. Choose platform (Chose Python).
6. Chose the "free tier" configuration.
7. The remaining network configurations were left as default ones.
8. Clicked on "Submit" button.

I also created two IAM roles. One role was created with the access for EC2 and the second role was given the access for ElasticBeanstalk. These two roles were used for configuration of the environment.